# ESP32-S3 SPI pins?

Tags: microcontroller, spi, esp8266, esp32, rfid

I am a beginner in electronics and tried to use ESP32-S3 for interfacing RFID and unable to find SPI pins in the the data-sheets. Tried Googling for pin reference but after reading so many blogs and data-sheets got more confused as some say "you can use any GPIO for SPI", "FSPID is MOSI, FSPIQ is MISO, etc".

Not a single clue till now which one is MISO, MOSI,CLK, IRQ. It would be a great help if anyone of you have used or worked with ESP32-S3.

Comment: Which data sheet you are reading and why are you unable to find it? Most PDF readers have a search function, have you tried searching for the word "SPI" or "MISO" or "MOSI"?

Comment: Looks like section 2.3.1 of the ESP32-S3 datasheet has the pin function information, but more important is section 3.5.2 which explains the capability of each of the 4 SPI peripherals, and Table 3.2 shows that the general-purpose SPI2/SPI3 use the GPIO matrix.

Answer (score 2):

You already found the correct answer:

> "you can use any GPIO for SPI"

... mostly. [1] [2]

The firmware code running on the ESP32 configures the SPI peripheral with the appropriate pins. They are not fixed in hardware. On the S3 (unlike some other ESP32 variants) there are no restrictions, but note this isn't true on other variants (a few pins on other variants are input-only with no output driver circuitry, for example). Always check the datasheet.

If you're using the [ESP-IDF](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32s3/index.html), look at the [SPI Master Driver documentation](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32s3/api-reference/peripherals/spi_master.html), particularly the [description of `struct spi_bus_config_t`](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32s3/api-reference/peripherals/spi_master.html#_CPPv416spi_bus_config_t):

> int mosi_io_num
>
> > GPIO pin for Master Out Slave In (=spi_d) signal, or -1 if not used.
>
> int data0_io_num
>
> > GPIO pin for spi data0 signal in quad/octal mode, or -1 if not used.
>
> int miso_io_num
>
> > GPIO pin for Master In Slave Out (=spi_q) signal, or -1 if not used.
>
> int data1_io_num
>
> > GPIO pin for spi data1 signal in quad/octal mode, or -1 if not used.
>
> int sclk_io_num
>
> > GPIO pin for SPI Clock signal, or -1 if not used.

[1] if you need high speeds (>= 26 MHz full duplex, >= 40 MHz half-duplex) you should avoid using the GPIO I/O mux and use the [direct connections](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32s3/api-reference/peripherals/spi_master.html#gpio-matrix-and-io-mux).

[2] some of the GPIOs are also used for strapping. If you use these, make sure the pin levels at reset release are correct for your strapping. For the ESP-32 that's GPIO0, GPIO3, GPIO45 and GPIO46. This is in [the datasheet](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-s3_datasheet_en.pdf).